# Convert y axis to radius in a circle

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a circle plot like this:

```
  dat <- data.frame(time = factor(rep(0:23,times = 20)),
                 count = sample(200,size = 480,replace = TRUE),
                 grp = sample(LETTERS[1:3],480,replace = TRUE))

ggplot(data = dat,aes(x = time,y  = count,fill = grp)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "stack") + 
    coord_polar()
```

How can I make the y axis to be the radius of the circle and have this prices?

Like this:
[image]

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are looking for. What's really the problem?

Comment: you can place the labels inside with `geom_text()` and disable the default y-axis using `theme()`

Comment: Ah, so your question is how to get the labels directly on the plot, rather than to one side as ggplot normally does?

Comment: `p + geom_text(aes(x=x,y=y,label=y), data=data.frame(x=0, y=seq(5, 35, by=5)), inherit.aes=F)`

Comment: Nice idea! But hard coding like that can be bypassed using `pretty()`. I've coded up a solution. There's probably something cleaner that can be done.

Comment: Caroline, maybe you could ask @baptiste to post a full answer or accept the one below if it works? If it doesn't so what you want, please provide some more information so people can try again?

Comment: @AndyClifton gave you a complete answer, didn't he?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change `geom_bar()` to `geom_line()` and alter the `aes()` call, you get the plot you want:

```
# set up the plotting environment
require('ggplot2')
theme_bw(base_size = 8, base_family = "")
# now generate the plot
p <- ggplot(data = dat,
            aes(x = time,
                y  = count,
                color = grp)) +    
    geom_line() + 
    coord_polar()

print(p)
```

Which gives you this:

[image]

It looks a little odd at the moment because your time data only includes hours. If you had decimal hours you might see more information.

The next step is fixing the axis labeling by figuring out good labels for a new one, setting the breaks on the y-axis, faking new tick labels using `geom_text()` and killing the old label  and ticks using `theme()`.

```
ybreaks <- pretty(x = data$count, n = 5)
p <- ggplot(data = data,
            aes(x = time, y  = count, color = grp)) + 
  geom_path() + 
  coord_polar() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = ybreaks) + 
  geom_text(data = data.frame(x = 0, y = ybreaks, label = ybreaks),
            aes(x = x, y = y, label = label),
            inherit.aes = F,
            size = 2) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(size = 0))
print(p)
```

And now you have your plot:

[image]

The advantage of using `pretty()` to set both the breaks and the labels on the y-axis is that your axis labeling changes automatically depending on the data that are plotted, and is aligned with the grid lines.

You have some fiddling around to do to get font sizes sorted out, but you are mostly there. For details of how to do this, maybe look at [the ggplot2 documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/).

Comment: see updates to answer. I've run with Baptiste's concept and tried to work through to the final answer.